# Why compound types with different order of components are equivalent in Scala?

Tags: scala

According to the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#equivalence),

> Two compound types are equivalent if the sequences of their component are pairwise equivalent, and occur in the same order, and their refinements are equivalent. Two refinements are equivalent if they bind the same names and the modifiers, types and bounds of every declared entity are equivalent in both refinements.

However, given

```
trait A { val a: Int }
trait B { val b: String }
```

I'm getting

```
scala> implicitly[A with B =:= B with A]
res0: =:=[A with B,B with A] = <function1>
```

i.e. they are considered equivalent, even though the order of components is different.  Why?

Comment: Are you sure these are the same concept? The scaladoc for `=:=` doesn't mention "equivalence", and the language spec section on type equivalence doesn't mention `=:=`, so it seems to me that these are simply different things.

Comment: @ChrisMartin "An instance of `A =:= B` witnesses that the types `A` and `B` are equal." — I assume that `equal` and `equivalent` mean the same thing, am I being wrong here?

Comment: In addition, to me when "equivalent" and "equal" are not the same, it is the latter that is stricter than the former (A and B being equivalent means that you can interchange them, but are not necessarily the same entity). However here it is the other way around, which seems counter-intuitive. Indeed the scaladoc for `Predef.=:=` says "An instance of A =:= B witnesses that the types A and B are **equal**" while the scala spec (quoted above) defines **type equivalence** (as witnessed by `Type # =:=`). But equivalence (`Type # =:=`) is here stricter than equality `Predef.=:=`. Peculiar indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `=:=` evidence only asserts that each is the upper bound of the other.

```
trait A; trait B

import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

val ab = ru.typeOf[A with B]
val ba = ru.typeOf[B with A]
ab =:= ba   // false!
ab <:< ba   // true!
ba <:< ab   // true!
```

The implicit from Predef you get basically if LUB(X, Y) == X == Y, because then the implicit resolution finds `=:=.tpEquals` with the inferred upper bound.

This is most likely what you want, because it means that you can treat one type as the other, and that works because the members of `A with B` are equal to the members of `B with A` even if the trait linearisation in the implementations is different.